# How to reference a previous prompt() in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I want to ask a user (through a prompt) if they would rather convert km to miles, or miles to km, within an else if statement. If neither condition is met, I want to go back to the conversion prompt:

```
var conversion = prompt("Do you want to convert miles to km, or km to miles?");
if (conversion=="miles to km") {
  [perform miles conversion here]
} else if (conversion=="km to miles") {
  [perform km conversion here]
} else {
  [go back to conversion prompt]
}
```

How would you code this line in JavaScript? Thanks.

Comment: `while(true) { do stuff }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var userHasMadeAChoice = false;

while(!userHasChosen)
{
    var conversion=prompt("Do you want to convert miles to km, or km to miles?");
    if (conversion=="miles to km") {
        [perform miles conversion here]
        userHasMadeAChoice = true;
    } else if (conversion=="km to miles") {
        [perform km conversion here]
        userHasMadeAChoice = true;
    }
}
```

Please do consider reading various articles on [Structured Programming](http://www.scribd.com/doc/38873257/Knuth-1974-Structured-Programming-With-Go-to-Statements)

Answer (score 1):

I could do it like that:

```
    var conversion;

    while (conversion === null || (conversion !== "miles to km" && conversion !== "km to miles")) {
        conversion = prompt('Do you want to convert miles to km, or km to miles?');
    }

    console.log(conversion);
```

Comment: No problem. This is a nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop:

```
while(true)
{
    var conversion=prompt("Do you want to convert miles to km, or km to miles?");
    if (conversion=="miles to km") {
        [perform miles conversion here]
        break;
    } else if (conversion=="km to miles") {
        [perform km conversion here]
        break;
    }
}
```

You can use a while loop and just set the condition to `true`. Then break out of the loop using `break` when one of the conditions is met.